# Convert List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> to List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, key-value

What is best way to convert `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` to `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`? 
 Precisely I have `Dictionary<string, string>` and when I use `ToList()` function, it converts to `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` but I want  `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` instead. How to achieve this? Besides I want this in place, not by using loops or any other unnecessary lines of codes. Thank you

---

Real Scenario:
There is a Web API project, in one of the endpoints `Body` of the request is `JsonElement` type. To parse the `Body` of the request I do this:

```
public JsonResult GetSomething([FromBody] JsonElement query){
    string rawJson = query.ToString();

    var keyValues = ParseRequestBodyHelper<Dictionary<string, string>>.ParseRequestBody(rawJson, "KeyValues");

}
```

`ParseRequestBodyHelper` gets type (`Dictionary<string, string>`) to deserialize object regard to filed name `KeyValues`. Now `keyValues` is `Dictionary<string, string>`.
After deserialization I want to log received information. My `Logger` gets a list of KeyValuePairs like this:

```
Logger.Instance.GetLogger().Information("Body of request parsed");
```

`GetLogger` function can take `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` as an input. I want to log `keyValues` alongside other information like this:

```
Logger.Instance.GetLogger(new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
                          {
                              new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Ip", IP),
                              new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Methodname", "GetSomething"),
                          })
               .Information("Body of request parsed");
```

If I do this

```
Logger.Instance.GetLogger(new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>(keyValues.ToList())
                          {
                              new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Ip", IP),
                              new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Methodname", "GetSomething"),
                          })
               .Information("Body of request parsed");
```

It gives me an error because `keyValues.ToList()` type is `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` but I want `List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`.
 
So now my entire problem is here. How do you think this could be solved?

Comment: A Dictionary is not a List.  You do not need to convert a Dictionary to a List since the Dictionary is already Enumerable.

Comment: since string _is_ object, I can't really see why to do that. Nor converting dictionary to list of `KeyValuePairs`. What is your goal?

Comment: why do you need a list of kvp in the first place? I can´t imagine why one would ever need this kind of conversion, maybe you can provide what you want to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Select` to create a `KeyValuePair` of the desired type:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
// fill with values
List<KeyValuePair<string,object>> objList = dictionary.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string,object>(x.Key, x.Value)).ToList();
```